# Exclude line/points from showing info when using add_tooltip with hover in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I've been playing around with the nice ggvis package. I'm doing a custom linear regression and wanted a tooltip to show info about each data point. However, when I add my regression line, the tooltip appears when I hover over the line, and shows then the info about the first datapoint (see screenshot). I provide this simple reproducible example:

```
library(ggvis)
mtc <- mtcars
lm=with(mtc,lm(mpg~wt))
mtc$fit=lm$coefficients[1]+mtcars$wt*lm$coefficients[2]
mtc$id <- 1:nrow(mtc)  # Add an id column to use ask the key

all_values <- function(x) {
    if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    row <- mtc[mtc$id == x$id, ]
    paste0(names(row), ": ", format(row), collapse = "
           ")
}

mtc %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, key := ~id) %>%
    layer_points() %>%layer_lines(x= ~wt,y= ~fit)%>% 
    add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
```

This produces this[image]

I would like to exclude the regression line from the tooltip so it only shows info about the data points. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of playing around I got it to work.

First of all I needed to construct two separate data sets for this to work. One for the linear model data and one for the mtcars.

## Solution

Constructing the data

```
mtc <- mtcars
mtc$id <- 1:nrow(mtc) 

lm=with(mtc,lm(mpg~wt))
df=data.frame(fit=lm$coefficients[1]+mtcars$wt*lm$coefficients[2])
df$id <- 101:132
df$wt <- mtcars$wt
```

As you can see above mtc is the data with the mtcars data and df is the linear model data. Notice that in the df I added an id column all of its values are greater than 100 and also completely different to the mtc data.frame.

Whenever you hover over points `all_values` will access the id column from mtc and whenever you hover over the line `all_values` will access the id column from df.

I added a line to your function below which is what makes it work:

```
all_values <- function(x) {
  #if the id is greater than 100 i.e. the df data.frame
  #then return NULL
  if(x$id>100) return(NULL)
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  row <- mtc[mtc$id == x$id, ]
  paste0(names(row), ": ", format(row), collapse = "
           ")
}
```

Then plot two separate data.frames. the `add_tooltip` will find the id variable for for both data.frames:

```
ggvis(x=~wt) %>%
     layer_points(data=mtc, y = ~mpg, key := ~id) %>%
     layer_paths(data=df,y= ~fit, key := ~id) %>%
     add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
```

I cannot show the full interactivity with this graph but you can see in the pic below that although my cursor is above the line no info is shown.

[image]

Whereas the points do show the info when hovered over.

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround. I had to do something similar once in a Shiny app; not very elegant. Hadley and Winston have this feature in the pipeline: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggvis/ktlFHhYcORM

Comment: Works perfectly! What is the reason for the use of layer_paths() instead of layer_lines? Also, does the df data fame require an id, that is, is the all_values function applied on every layer of the ggvis plot?

Comment: @Sölvi I used `layer_paths` because it works great with multiple data sets. `layer_lines` seems to fail with that. As for the id column in the df data.frame, maybe it doesn't necessarily require it. When you hover over the line, `x` in `all_values` becomes `df`. So you can use which ever value/column in the if condition to make it return NULL. You need to use a condition though otherwise `all_values` will fail. You had used an id for the mtc data.frame so it made sense for me to use the same :)